# How switch Route when using method Url.Action in UrlHelper MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have following define route ,

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "sp",
                url: "sp/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "pm",
                url: "pm/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

when running, url of my project like to "http://example.com:7549/nhj/pm" and "http://example.com:7549/nhj/sp"

But, when using method Url.Action("Edit", "Product"), the Url has been generated by method Url.Action is  always `"http://example.com:7549/nhj/sp/Product/Edit"`.

How can I use the method Url.Action("Edit", "Product") to generate two different urls that are "http://example.com:7549/nhj/pm/Product/Edit" and "http://example.com:7549/nhj/sp/Product/Edit" match with 2 routes above.

Anyone can you help me??? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Url.RouteLink()` that is using the route name when generating the Url:

```
// for SP route
Url.RouteUrl("sp", new { action = "Edit", controller = "Product" });

// for PM route
Url.RouteUrl("pm", new { action = "Edit", controller = "Product" });
```

When you're using the returned Url to redirect from action, use:

```
// for SP route
return RedirectToRoute("sp", new { action = "Edit", controller = "Product" });

// for PM route
return RedirectToRoute("pm", new { action = "Edit", controller = "Product" });
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for answer, but,if generate to "http://example.com:7549/nhj/pm/Product/Edit" url, how do?

Comment: I modified the answer.

Comment: thanks you, but in controller when using method RedirectToAction still redirect to different url, can't control it...

Comment: Because in current source, Url.Action is used in many places, so modification from  Url.Action  to Url.RouteUrl takes long time. Is there any way that can change the using current route of URLHeleper??? Then, just call the Url.Action, depends on the current route, approriate URL will appear

Comment: Since the regular `Url.Action` helper doesn't consider your current route, you'll have to introduce your own overload that does and that also means changing the way you call to the function (perhaps adding an extract `bool` parameter). So *something* will have to change in all the places you call `Url.Action`.